# How to replicate app to use with different resources in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Hi I have a small android app that serves as client for a network, now I need to replicate the app, just changing url's, colors, and png´s, I believe there is way to manage this through grade, but I`m not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make Product Flavors for your application.

Look at this tutorial:

https://objectpartners.com/2015/03/31/using-android-product-flavors-to-build-full-and-demo-version-of-the-app/

Cheers.